# How can I find all .mp3 files stored on the internal storage of my phone?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, storage, android-permissions

I'm working on an android app, an mp3 player to be precise, and I would like to add all the .mp3 files it can find on the phone to the library. The problem is that it seems like the android app gets installed in a strange folder (I am unable to find the folder on my phone) and only searches files in that folder. In my AndroidManifest file, I added this line of code to ask for permissions and it works fine:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I also tried to emulate the app on Android studio and I noticed that the app got located in a folder like */storage/emulated/0* and it only searched for files in that directory.
This is my method to search for files:

```
    public ArrayList<File> findSong (File file) {
        ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        if (files != null) {
            for (File singlefile : files) {
                if (singlefile.isDirectory() && !singlefile.isHidden()) {
                    arrayList.addAll(findSong(singlefile));
                } else {
                    if (singlefile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singlefile.getName().endsWith(".wav")) {
                        arrayList.add(singlefile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

And this is the function to display the songs in a list:

```
    void displaySongs() {
        final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        items = new String[mySongs.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i<mySongs.size(); i++) {
            items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3", "")
                    .replace(".wav", "");

        }
        /*
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        */

        customAdapter customAdapter = new customAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String songName = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerActivity.class)
                .putExtra("songs", mySongs)
                .putExtra("songname", songName)
                .putExtra("pos", position));
            }
        });
    }
```

The songs get listed like this and when you click on them the player opens and starts playing the song:

[image: Screenshot of how the songs get listed on the app]

I'm new at all this, but what the method should do is search through all files in the phone's storage and add to the list those who end with either .mp3 or .wav.
Any help, explanation, and/or feedback is highly appreciated. If you need some more information I will be happy to share it with you.

Comment: Query the `MediaStore` for content with the `audio/mp3` MIME type.

Comment: Isn't there a way that my app searches in the internal storage instead of the /storage/emulated/0 directory?

Comment: That would be much slower. `MediaStore` is a database of the available media. A query of that can be very fast, compared to manually scanning each and every directory. Also, `MediaStore` can index media that you would have difficulty scanning directly yourself.

Comment: Ok, and how do I implement it in my method? I never did anything with MediaStore

Comment: [The answer that you were given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67586363/115145) shows how to query `MediaStore`, though the answer has formatting issues and assumes that you create an `AudioModel` class that you are building out of the `Cursor` results. [This sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/blob/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/conferencevideos/VideoRepository.kt) shows querying `MediaStore`, though it is for videos and is in Kotlin.

Comment: [This older sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v9.0/RecyclerView/VideoList/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/recyclerview/videolist/MainActivity.java) shows querying `MediaStore` in Java, though it is for videos and uses `CursorLoader`, which is somewhat obsolete. Most likely you can find other discussions about `MediaStore` elsewhere on this site or on the broader Internet.

Comment: The problem is that I require it to return a File. I need it later to play it with the MediaPlayer. If you look at my second code snippet, it is searching the songs in the internal Directory using [this function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) to get the path to it

Comment: "I need it later to play it with the MediaPlayer" -- `MediaPlayer` does not require a `File`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer).

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<AudioModel> getAllAudioFromDevice(final Context context) {
 
   final List<AudioModel> tempAudioList = new ArrayList<>();

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, 
    MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM, 
    MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.ARTIST,};

// if want from specific folder
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[]{"%utm%"}, null);



// if want fetch all files
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
    projection,
    null,
    null,
    null);
    

        if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            AudioModel audioModel = new AudioModel();
            String path = c.getString(0);
            String name = c.getString(1);
            String album = c.getString(2);
            String artist = c.getString(3);

            audioModel.setaName(name);
            audioModel.setaAlbum(album);
            audioModel.setaArtist(artist);
            audioModel.setaPath(path);

            Log.e("Name :" + name, " Album :" + album);
            Log.e("Path :" + path, " Artist :" + artist);

            tempAudioList.add(audioModel);
        }
        c.close();
    }

    return tempAudioList;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it gives me an error saying that AudioModel doesn't exist

Comment: Audio model is normal data class you can create dont copy paste the whole thing. take the logic only and implement urself

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the second code snippet I have in the answer, you can see that I tell the app to search in a Directory by using a deprecated Function:

```
 final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

[Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) is deprecated in API level 29.
Now I didn't notice it because the API I am using is 23 and there was no error while trying the app in the emulator. But when I tried it on my Samsung s9 there was obviously a problem because the API there is definitely higher.
Luckily I found a very easy fix. It's probably neither the best nor the most efficient, all I'm saying is that it worked for me:
Just add the following line in your Manifest file in the application-tag:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

What it does is somehow give external storage permissions on newer devices too.
I don't know exactly how it works. I'm gonna leave this here because maybe in the future it might help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

using MediaStore.Audio

```
        private void lodfrmdvic() {
        linearlayout.removeAllViews();//clear albums or favs or ondevic
        //LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        dataaray = new ArrayList<>();
        titlaray = new ArrayList<>();
        albmaray = new ArrayList<>();
        artstaray = new ArrayList<>();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
        final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;//params.gravity = Gravity.END;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                final int curndx =cursor.getPosition();
                /** when using cursor.getPosition() make failre becase it set in title.setOnClickListener the last valu(cursor Counts)
                using int or string then insert it in title.setOnClickListener solve problem */
                final String dsnam = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));//title+extion
                final String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                //final String titl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                final String titl = dsnam.replace( dsnam.substring(dsnam.lastIndexOf(".")) ,"");//to show titl=filename wthot exton
                // Save to arrays
                dataaray.add(data);
                titlaray.add(titl);
                albmaray.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)));
                artstaray.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)));
                LinearLayout mrow = new LinearLayout(this);
                mrow.setPadding(0,20,0,20);
                TextView title =new TextView(this);
                //title.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
                title.setLayoutParams(params);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {//17
                    title.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);//for start arabic if app lang is english and vice versa
                }
                ImageButton mor = new ImageButton(this);
                //to short long title
                String shrttitl = titl;
                if(titl.length()>30){shrttitl=titl.substring(0,30)+"...";}//show till and ltr 30
                title.setText(shrttitl);
                mrow.addView(title);
                //if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21){mor.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_cloud_upload_24));}
                //else{mor.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_cloud_upload_24));}
                mor.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_baseline_cloud_upload_24, getTheme()));
                mrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) {playaudio(curndx);} });
                mor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Showsonds.this);
                    // builder.setTitle("del?");
                    // builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.ad)+" "+titl+" "+getString(R.string.tomyclod))
                            .setPositiveButton( getString(R.string.yes) , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { adtomine(data,dsnam,titl); }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton( getString(R.string.cncl) , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { dialog.cancel(); }
                            });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                } });
                mrow.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                        //toast("looooooooong clk");
                        //todo show >>
                        toast(titl);

                        return true;
                    } });
                mrow.addView(mor);
                linearlayout.addView(mrow);
            }cursor.close();
        }
    }
```